# Adaptive Cards Input Values in Submit

Tags: javascript, sdk, adaptive-cards

Hi I'm using the Adaptive card SDK in a web page, using a Sample Card like this:

```
  var card = {
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.0",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "Present a form and submit it back to the originator"
    },
    {
        "type": "Input.Text",
        "id": "firstName",
        "placeholder": "What is your first name?"
    },
    {
        "type": "Input.Text",
        "id": "lastName",
        "placeholder": "What is your last name?"
    }
],
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.Submit",
        "title": "Action.Submit"
    }
]};
```

and rendering using the usual rubric. I'd like to get the inputs back with the submit so I tried this

```
     // Set the adaptive card's event handlers. onExecuteAction is invoked
    // whenever an action is clicked in the card
    adaptiveCard.onExecuteAction = function (action) { console.log(action.toJSON()) }
```

which just gives me:
`Object title: "Action.Submit" type: "Action.Submit" __proto__: Object`

How do I get the values of the input fields on the submit action?

TIA for any comments, advice and answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `data` property of the *action object* just like this:

```
  adaptiveCard.onExecuteAction = function (action) {
    alert(`Hello ${action.data.firstName} ${action.data.lastName}`);
  }
```

Here's a full [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmfrxynz/4/).

[image: Sample submit]

There are many other interesting properties on the *action object*, but I haven't found good documentation.
However, the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/blob/ca928082f041023047e7d612e11661bd25b579d3/source/community/reactnative/src/visualizer/renderer.js#L157) of the adaptive card visualizer contains some usage examples.

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian, you are a true lifesaver. We are just starting out with Adaptive Cards and just feeling our way. We may have more questions! (We do have a small R&D budget too ;-))

Comment: Happy to help, Mike! It takes a little while to get warm with adaptive cards. Answering your question was a good refresher for me ;) all the best!

Comment: Have a look at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=madewithcardsio.adaptivecardsstudiobeta and the coresponding code: https://github.com/madewithcards/adaptivecardsstudio  maybe it helps a bit

Comment: Nice project, Tim! Thanks for sharing!